# Trying to select the least common value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select the least common value. For example, if my data looks like this,

```
0810 - City 0810
0810 - City 0810
0810 - City 0810
0810 - City 0810
0810 - City 0810
0810 - City 0810
0810 - City 0810
0145 - London 0145
0900 - City2 0900
0900 - City2 0900
```

I want the result `0145 - London 0145`.

Comment: is there ever going to be more than one different one?

Comment: Yes there may well be.

Comment: if there are multiple, are you wanting to select all of them?

Comment: Only the one or ones that are different, there will only ever be 3 max that is different from the rest. Note that i wont know what the majority will be.

Comment: I tsql I would do something like: `select * from (select count(ID) as IDTotal, ID group by ID) as T where IDTotal < 
(select max(A.IDTotal) from (select count(ID) as IDTotal, ID group by ID) as A)` But I don't have any experience with oracle queries.

Comment: How do you define which one is "different"? Different from what? Are you going to compute the most frequent value and compare against that, or are you going to hard code an expected value, or what?

Comment: Maybe use `distinct`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "different"? Do you want to see the rows where that column's value only appears once in the table? Or hide everything that appears more then once?

Comment: I am trying to find the least common result

Comment: I've made a major edit. Please verify that I have accurately captured what you want to do. Also, what do you want to happen if there is more than one value with the same, lowest count (for example, if there are two different values that appear only once)?

Comment: Yes if there are 2-3 or more then i want it to show that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other data conditions you had in mind, but I'm pretty sure something like the following is heading in the right direction:

```
with my_tab as
(
select '0810 - City 0810' my_col from dual union all
select '0810 - City 0810' my_col from dual union all
select '0810 - City 0810' my_col from dual union all
select '0810 - City 0810' my_col from dual union all
select '0810 - City 0810' my_col from dual union all
select '0810 - City 0810' my_col from dual union all
select '0810 - City 0810' my_col from dual union all
select '0123 - Raleigh 0123' my_col from dual union all
select '0123 - Raleigh 0123' my_col from dual union all
select '0145 - London 0145' my_col from dual 
)
, my_group as
(
select my_col, count(*) cnt
from my_tab
group by my_col
)
select my_col 
from my_group
where cnt < (select max(cnt) from my_group)
;
```